# One-to-Many-to-One with attributes Form with Symfony 3 / Doctrine

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database

Here is the problem :

I have a model with 3 classes

- person
- person_job
- job

A person can have several jobs, any job-person relation can have a "date_start" attribute, "date_end", and "comment". So I built this model with a jointable (person_job) holding these attributes, and making the relationship on 2 manyToOne attributes called person and job (generated with doctrine annotations)

Person attributes looks like :

```
/**
* @var string
* @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string",length=255,nullable=false)
*/
private $name;

/**
* @var string
* @ORM\Column(name="firstname",type="string",length=255,nullable=true)
*/
private $firstname;
/**
* @var bool
* @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
*/
private $active;
```

Job attributes looks like this :

```
/**
* @var string
* @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string",length=255,nullable=false)
*/
private $name;
```

person_job looks like this :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\Person")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $person;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\Job")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $job;

/**
* @var string 
* @ORM\Column(name="comment",type="string",length=255,nullable=true)
*/
private $comment;

/**
* @var \DateTime
* @ORM\Column(name="startdate",type="datetime")
*/
private $datestart;

/**
* @var \DateTime
* @ORM\Column(name="enddate",type="datetime")
*/
private $dateend;
```

Now I'd like to build a form, for my "person" where I can choose jobs in a list, and add (if needed) date_start, date_end, or comment related to this job. My FormBuilder looks like this for "Person" :

```
$builder
  ->add('name')
  ->add('firstname')
  ->add('jobs',Job::class,array('label'=>'Job'));
```

This fails. My Person class has no "jobs" attribute.. So, how can I achieve such things? do I have to add a jobs attribute, with a oneToMany relation on it, declared with "mappedBy"?

These relationships in doctrine still make me confused, I'm new to symfony, I looked on the internet but didn't find a decent solution/example yet...

Thanks for reading/help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have come accross one of the hardest problems with Symfony forms. Fortunately, there is some good documentation. Let me summarize the important steps.

You’re right: The entity Person needs to know about its relationship with PersonJob if you want to manipulate that relationship from a Person’s point of view. So you need to add a property:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Person.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonJob", mappedBy="person")
 */
private $personJobs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->personJobs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

and then you will have in the form type

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/PersonType.php
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('firstname')
    ->add('personJobs', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type'   => PersonJobType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
    )
;
```

Note the type of the `personJobs` field. Since a person can have many PersonJobs, you need a form type that can handle collections. This is the purpose of the built-in `CollectionType` (check out [its documentation!](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)). You also need the form type `PersonJobType`, so that `CollectionType` knows how to build the sub-forms:

```
class PersonJobType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('comment')
            ->add('datestart', DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('dateend', DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('job') // requires Job::__toString() to be defined!
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob'
        ));
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes, change your controller to

```
 public function testAction()
 {
    $person = new Person();
    $form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);
    $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        print '<pre>';
        var_dump($form->getData());
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Now go ahead and copy & paste the Twig and Javascript code from [Adding and Removing Items](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items) (you have to make minor changes such as replacing `form.emails` with `form.personJobs`).

### The form

The form will look like

Just the Person form with a *“Add another PersonJob”* link:

[image: First step]

Adding a PersonJob:

[image: Adding a PersonJob]

Adding anothing PersonJob:

[image: Adding another PersonJob]

## The data received

Submit the form and see the output of `var_dump`:

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\Person)#247 (5) {
  ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\Person":private]=>
  NULL
  ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\Person":private]=>
  string(12) "Charles Dude"
  ["firstName":"AppBundle\Entity\Person":private]=>
  string(7) "Charles"
  ["active":"AppBundle\Entity\Person":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["personJobs":"AppBundle\Entity\Person":private]=>
  object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#248 (1) {
    ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob)#962 (6) {
        ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob":private]=>
        NULL
        ["comment":"AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob":private]=>
        string(19) "Something important"
        ["datestart":"AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob":private]=> 
        object(DateTime)#1088 (3) { … }
        ["dateend": …] => …
        ["person":"AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob":private]=>
        NULL
        ["job":"AppBundle\Entity\PersonJob":private]=>
        object(AppBundle\Entity\Job)#1171 (2) {
          ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>
          int(2)
          ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>
          string(5) "Job 2"
        }
      }
      [1]=> …
  }
}
```

Two things remain to be done:

1. Set the `person` property of the nested `PersonJob` entities properly to the new (but not yet persisted) Person.
2. Tell Doctrine about the new `PersonJob` entities by calling `$em->persist(…)` on them.

### Relevant documentation:

- [CollectionType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)
- [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I do not have the error anymore, but my form still has no "list" to choose a job... I use your code, I add "label"=>"Jobs", and I only have the label showing... no collection/select available in form... :O

Comment: How does your PersonJobType look like? (You might want to edit it into your question, it’s probably short enough.)

Comment: Well I generated it with command line, it's just "$builder->add('person')->add('job')", that's probably the problem as you suggest...

Comment: I’m sorry, I think I misunderstood you. You should add the option `'allow_add' => true` to the `personJobs` field.

Comment: When I allow_add, I get the "catchable fatal error : object of class ...\Person could not be converted to string"... (createChoiceLabel($choice) function)

Comment: Interesting. I will look into it and reply.

Comment: What I can do is : ->add('personJobs',Entity::class,array('class'=>Job::class,'choice_label'=>'name')) BUT this is not related to my "personJob" jointable... and, I do not have the possibility to add "dateStart", "dateEnd", "comment"...

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation for [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)? There is an example that shows how to add new entities to a collection with the help of some Javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115695/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-lumen).

Comment: just for knowledge purposes, is it possible to do that with "entity type class" instead of "CollectionType::class", and what would it change? is it a "better" or "more common" solution?

Comment: You could use `EntityType` with `'multiple' => true`, but that’s most likely not what you want. You would see a list of *existing* `PersonJob` entities, where you actually want to create *new* `PersonJob` entities to connect a Person to an existing Job.

Comment: Following this I get an out of memory error on symfony 4. I also have a very similar situation, Buyer OneToMany(Bidirectional) to BuyerContacts ManyToOne(Unidirectional) Contacts.